# Grunt task to optionally include an AMD module for different environment

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs

I'm developing a web app using Require.js for AMD and amplify.request to abstract away my AJAX calls. The other advantage to amplify.request is that I've defined an alternative module containing mocked versions of my requests that I can use for testing purposes. Currently, I'm switching between the two versions of my request module by simply commenting/un-commenting the module reference in my main.js file.

What I'd love to do is use Grunt to create different builds of my app depending on which module I wanted included. I could also use it to do things like turn my debug mode on or off. I'm picturing something similar to [usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin), only for references inside JavaScript, not HTML.

Anyone know of a plugin that does this, or have a suggestion about how I could do it with Grunt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On our current project we have a few different environments. For each of them, we can specify different configuration settings for the requirejs build.
To distinguish between these different environments, I've used a parameter `target`.

You can simply pass this to grunt by appending it to your call like

```
grunt --target=debug
```

And you can access this parameter in the Gruntfile, by using `grunt.option`, like

```
var target = (grunt.option('target') || 'debug').toLowerCase();
```

The line above will default to `debug`. You could then make use of the `paths` configuration setting of requirejs to point the build to the correct module. Example code below.

```
requirejs: {
    compile: {
        options: {  
            paths: {
                "your/path/to/amplify/request": target === "debug" ? "path/to/mock" : "path/to/real",
                }   
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: That's really helpful, and will totally work for letting me use/not use specific modules depending on environment. Any ideas for editing specific variables in my code (for instance, to turn on/off a debug setting?). I suppose I could just create a separate module with the variable set a different way, but I'd rather set it dynamically if at all possible.

Comment: How about defining a settings module containing switch variables? Depending on the target variable you could load in another module, containing different values for those switch values. On our project we have such a module (AppSettings), but instead of loading in another module, we override the settings using the `onBuildWrite` option of requirejs.

Comment: Wow, `onBuildWrite` is a pretty powerful option I wasn't aware of. That would certainly fit the bill, I think, or I could do as you suggested and just swap out the whole module. Thanks!