# Looking for preprocessor for JavaScript Backbone App

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, preprocessor

I am looking for best preprocessor solution for this type of project.

I am creating medium `Backbone.js` single page app that need to have certn structure. Like debug directives in all js files (backbone models, views and collections), also including test functions and framework.

For example (pseudocode)  :

```
#if TEST
include test.js // test framework
...
#elseif DEBUG
include debug.js (extension of models that log to console save/fetch/delete actions etc)
...
#end
```

Preprocessor needs to combine all listed js files and create three different version of single js file (prod, dev, test).

Is there `JavaScript` preprocessor that can handle that task?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use that preprocessor for dependency management (including dependencies)? In your example, what makes the difference of `test.js` and `debug.js`? Do you insist on such a solution even if there are alternative solutions? Why do you want to build one application with conditionally added test framework or debugging dependencies while you could build three environments where you include one application together with a debugging or a testing lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use [MetaScript](https://github.com/dcodeIO/MetaScript) . It have all that I need, example :

Comment include :

```
/*? if (NODE)
    include("node-stuff.js");
else
    include("browser-stuff.js"); */
```

Comment variables

```
//? var NODE = true;     // Local
//? NODE = true;         // Global
```

And other features that I need. Downside is that requires `nodejs-legacy` lib (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://requirejs.org/. You can use Grunt's require js (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) to compress/join your files.

Comment: thanks for answer but I can't find any example of '#if' like statement in `requirejs`

Comment: Found this [plugin](http://jaketrent.com/post/an-environment-specific-grunt-build/) for grunt. Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383209/grunt-task-to-optionally-include-an-amd-module-for-different-environment) post for another approach.

Comment: This doesn't solve problem if I have code something like this `... #if debug console.log(...);` It's ok for files but not inline exclusion.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one one – *Builder*, which among other features supports includes directly from GitHub: https://github.com/electricimp/Builder

Little example

```
@include once "github:jquery/jquery/build/release.js@2.2.3"

@set ABC 123

@if ABC > 123
  //
@else
  //
@end
```